# Why does wireshark get extremely slow on macOS 10.12

Tags: wireshark, macos-sierra

I've tried on 3 devices including rMBP 2015/2016 and Wireshark still works very slow. It takes nearly 2 seconds to highlight a option after the cursor hang over on it.
I have disabled name resolution.

Since it works fine on macOS 10.11 on an older device, it seems that Wireshark doesn't prepare for macOS 10.12 yet?

Answer (score 0):

How you execute it? I tried to execute Wireshark with a virtual machine and it was also very slow, then I try it with a program called wineskin winery and it works fine, you just have to install that software and the .exe file for windows from wireshark.

Comment: Now in 10.13 Wiresharks works fine. I think the problem is only in 10.12.